# unity changing weapons.prefab issues

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i'm trying to change weapons for my 2d top down space shooter. by weapon I just mean my bullet prefab so it shoots a different bullet which I can then add damage to etc.

here is the code  I have. when I press number 2 it shoots my prefab clone in the hierarchy but its greyed out and nothing shows up in the game view. Below is my playerShoot code.

```
public class playerShoot : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 bulletOffset = new Vector3 (0, 0.5f, 0);
float cooldownTimer = 0;
public float fireDelay = 0.25f;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
int bulletLayer;

public int currentWeapon;
public Transform[] weapons;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)){
        ChangeWeapon(0);

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)){
        ChangeWeapon(1);

    }

    cooldownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && cooldownTimer <= 0){
        cooldownTimer = fireDelay;
        Vector3 offset = transform.rotation * bulletOffset;
        GameObject bulletGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position + offset, transform.rotation);
        bulletGO.layer =gameObject.layer;
    }


}

public void ChangeWeapon(int num){
    currentWeapon = num;
    for (int i = 0; i < weapons.Length; i++){
        if (i ==num)
            weapons[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        else
            weapons[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show how it looks (Hierarchy and inspector setup of the script)

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios here is a screenshot, thanks http://i.imgur.com/pf0d1Bw.jpg

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios sorry here's a better image http://i.imgur.com/RGayi3x.jpg

Comment: The problem seems to be simple. You seem to have used the prefab of the bullet as the elements of your weapons array. I'll post some sample code in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the rest of the code same, just change the following line

```
GameObject bulletGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position + offset, transform.rotation);
```

to

```
GameObject bulletGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(weapons[currentWeapon].gameObject, transform.position + offset, transform.rotation);
```

What the change does is use the transforms for the weapons in your weapon array, rather than using the bulletPrefab.

The problem occured because you were Instantiating a single prefab, which was the same as the Transform you used for the first element in your weapons array. So, when you call **ChangeWeapon(1)**, the prefab would get deactivated. This reulted in inactive GameObjects being instantiated.

What I would suggest you do is to have two separate prefabs and spawn those accordingly.